# How to get certain parts of a BeautifulSoup Object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am scraping a table on Wikipedia without a class and getting the following output so far:

```
<a href="/wiki/link1" title="name1">name1</a>
<a href="/wiki/link2" title="name2">name2</a>
<a href="/wiki/link3" title="name3">name3</a>
```

What I need is the **content within the quotes** and the **name between the angle brackets**, but I couldn't find out how to get it. This is my code so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population'
source_code = requests.get(url)                     # Read source code
plain_text = source_code.text                       # Source code in unicode
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")     # create BS object

table = soup.find(text="2016 rank").find_parent("table")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    print(row.find_all('a')[0])
```

I am new to BS hand have to figure out how it works right. Hope somebody can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values contained within the quotes, you can use `.attrs` field - it's a dictionary tag attributes and their values:

```
print(row.find_all('a')[0].attrs['href'])
print(row.find_all('a')[0].attrs['title'])
```

To pull out the part after the `>` character, you can use `.contents`:

```
print(row.find_all('a')[0].contents)
```